# I'm using Puppeteer to run Mapbox in Chrome on a Heroku server and I'm running into massive slowdowns. What could be causing this?

Tags: heroku, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

If I use a sufficiently small canvas, everything works fine, but I need to use a large (1000x1000 pixel) canvas.

Just instantiating the Mapbox object takes about 10 seconds to run. When I start trying to do my animation I get logs as follows:

2023-11-13T00:11:16.041106+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=792M(104.9%)2023-11-13T00:11:16.043049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

I've tried using a beefier dyno but I still get similar slowness (although the memory errors go away). Everything runs smoothly (sub second) on my Mac, even when I disabled the gpu in my Mac chrome in order to try to reproduce the problem.

Does anyone have any ideas how I might figure out what's going on here?

Comment: I'm curious about this as I am planning to do something similar. Runs fine locally but have not tested it on a remote server.